# Websockets on Tomcat 8 + IIS 8 with ARR 3 are not working

Tags: java, tomcat, iis, websocket, arr

I've scoured the internet trying to find anyone who might be experiencing this issue but come up empty handed. So here goes:

We have a java web application (based on Spring MVC 4). It sits behind Microsoft IIS acting as a load balancer / reverse proxy using Application Request Routing (ARR) v3.

This IIS is performing load balancing with ARR for 3 different environments (all running the **same** Java code): `dev.example.com`, `demo.example.com` and `qa.example.com`.

The application serves notifications to users' browsers using WebSockets via SockJS and stompjs and this has all been working well while the application servers were on Tomcat 7. After upgrading the `qa.example.com` environment to Tomcat 8, the WebSocket connections stopped working - it falls back to XHR POST requests.

I want to stress that no changes were made to IIS, just the `qa` application server.

**Here is a sample request/response from the `dev` environment (working):**

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Cookie: <cookies snipped>
Host: dev.example.com
Origin: https://dev.example.com
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: E7aIek0X6qcO9PAl1n6w4Q==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36
```

Response

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: Upgrade
Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2015 02:19:35 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: dKYK05s4eP87iA20aSo/3ntOrPU=
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Upgrade: Websocket
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

**Here is a sample request/response from the `qa` environment (broken):**

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Cookie: <cookies snipped>
Host: qa.example.com
Origin: https://qa.example.com
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: jTOIAT0+o35+Qi0ZWh2gyQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36
```

Response:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: Upgrade
Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2015 02:18:30 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: P+fEH8pvxcu3sEoO5fDizjSbwJc=
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate;client_max_window_bits=15
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Upgrade: Websocket
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

The only obvious difference is that the `qa` response includes a `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate;client_max_window_bits=15` header while the `dev` response does not.

I turned on "Failed Request Tracing" on IIS to debug the `101` response and I can see that there are some headers that get overwritten by IIS - the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header namely.

IIS also shows that that request is creating a `502.5` error. I looked that up and found this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943891 which says that `502.5` is "WebSocket failure (ARR)" and that's all it says. Weirdly enough though, Chrome Dev Tools shows that it responds with a 101 just like it's supposed to...

I tried this all with a local application server (Tomcat 8 with no IIS) and the websockets worked just fine. Tomcat 7 + IIS + ARR + WebSockets works just fine. Tomcat 8 + IIS + ARR + WebSockets does not.

My exact version of Tomcat 8 is 8.0.28 - but I got the same results on Tomcat 8.0.26.

My next step it to keep downgrading Tomcat 8 through minor versions and see if anything changes. I will update here if I discover anything.

## Update

Here's a response from my local server (no IIS):

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: upgrade
Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2015 13:59:23 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 718HnPxHN8crYYzNGFjQf7w8O+Y=
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate;client_max_window_bits=15
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Upgrade: websocket
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

It looks a lot like the broken `qa` request, but it works great. So I guess the `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` thing was a red herring. Also `Upgrade: websocket` and `Connection: upgrade` is lower case on my local server, whereas it is `Websocket` and `Upgrade` when you put IIS in front.

`Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` also has a trailing space in `qa` after the `permessage-deflate;` but the local does not.

## Update 2

It all works fine on the `qa` environment in Microsoft Edge (Windows 10) I haven't tried Internet Explorer 11, but I have to assume it probably also works. Firefox and Chrome on OSX do not work.

## Update 3

Request from Tomcat before it gets modified by IIS/ARR:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: luP49lroNK9qTdaNNnSCLXnxAWc=
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate;client_max_window_bits=15
Date: Tue, 27 Oct 2015 21:10:48 GMT
```

Comment: Are you able to disable compression on websockets for Tomcat? Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; suggests it is getting compressed, in my experience IIS didn't proxy compressed websockets.

Comment: @timmah.faase I will give it a shot and report back

Comment: So, I attempted to add this option to my Tomcat config: `-Dorg.apache.tomcat.websocket.DISABLE_BUILTIN_EXTENSIONS=true` which was supposed to do the trick according to the docs: `If true, disable all built-in extensions provided by the server, such as message compression.` but it doesn't seem to have changed the response headers at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have discovered the solution, although it is not as satisfying as I wish it was.

In our project's `pom.xml` we had `spring-core:4.2.5` but `spring-websocket` and `spring-messaging` were `4.1.6`. The version mismatch was causing some issues clearly.

Setting `-Dorg.apache.tomcat.websocket.DISABLE_BUILTIN_EXTENSIONS=true` in the Tomcat startup options when the versions were **mismatched** had no effect. Setting that JVM option when the versions were **the same** worked as expected.

The `101` response now does not contain `permessage-deflate` and websockets are able to connect with no issues through IIS. Our application does not send a lot of data through the sockets so we were OK making this tradeoff.

Comment: All spring libs that I'm using are are 4.3.6 and I am too experiencing this issue. I can confirm that disabling the websocket extensions works but I have to agree that this is not a very satisfying solution as compression goes out the door. Any other solution would be most welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same Problem.
The Workaround is to override the Websockets compression handling header from the Client with ARR.
IE dosen't force or try Websocket Compression but Chrome and Firefox will issue the Request with a Header "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate".

Since I could not influence my NodeJS backend server, I had to solve this in the ARR.

Have a Look at this article.

https://community.home-assistant.io/t/solved-access-via-iis-reverse-proxy-died-after-upgrade-to-0-58/34408

It worked for me.

After the Modifications the Header was overriden with a blank value in my inbound Rewrite Rule and ARR had no Problems to handle Websocket Requests and Responses because they were not compressed by this and ARR could handle them with the activated Websockets module in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

The same problem on Tomcat7 and IIS8 using ARR3. We are not using Spring libraries.

No frames are sent after the websocket connection is established if websocket-extensiones are enabled. But if we disabled websocket-extensions then all works perfectly.

Comment: I wonder how we could file a bug report for this - it seems like a bug for sure! Is there a Microsoft Connect for IIS I wonder...

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with the Azure AD Application Proxy in front of Tomcat. We had to disable the Sec-WebSocket-Extensions in Tomcat.