# IIS 8 WebSockets with permessage-deflate

Tags: .net, iis, websocket, http-compression

I am trying to enable the WebSocket-Extension `permessage-deflate` in IIS 8, but with no luck so far. It seems, that IIS does not support any extensions and does not respond with an `Sec-WebSockets-Extension` header.

I tried to send it manually via `Response.Headers.Add("Sec-WebSockets-Extension", "permessage-deflate; client_no_context_takeover; server_no_context_takeover")` and did the compression/decompression via `DeflateStream` by hand before sending/after receiving, but then the receive methods of the WebSocket failed.

I also tried to implement the WebSocket manually as an OWIN-Middleware (with the help of the library [vtortola](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener)), but IIS keeps closing my `InputStream` and reading of data is not possible.

Did anyone successfully enable this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible through `System.Web.WebSockets`.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7692#section-6

Although you can indicate the HTTP headers for the deflate mode, the messages need to have activated the bit RSV1 in order to be identified as compressed:

> This document allocates the RSV1 bit of the WebSocket header for PMCEs
> and calls the bit the "Per-Message Compressed" bit.  On a WebSocket
> connection where a PMCE is in use, this bit indicates whether a
> message is compressed or not.

So even if you compress the payload, since the message header does not have the compression bit on, the receiver will still try to read as uncompressed. Once you negotiated the deflate mode through the HTTP upgrade mechanism, you can still send compressed and uncompressed messages together, and the reason for this is that deflate is not effective with small payloads, so there are messages that may not be worth to compress.

That said, since the WebSocket API in ASP.NET does not allow you to work out the message options, I am afraid this cannot be done.

Now, about OWIN. I have to say I have not explored this path, however, I doubt that is possible, at least integrated with IIS8 in the same port than HTTP, that is probably what you want to do.

Comment: The question would then be this: have you thought about integrating your websocket library with a custom owin middleware? Wouldn't that be possible?

Comment: I thought about that, but considering that it would not be able of running in the same TCP port than IIS8 I lost interest. Technically it should be possible, but I have never tried to do something similar.

Comment: And with possible, I mean possible to use it in OWIN in a self-hosted app, not in IIS8.

Comment: Thank you very much for thorough explanation and ideas! I've rewarded you the 50 points :) well deserved!